# Getting null as a result

Tags: php, sqlite, laravel, laravel-5

I have created two tables, First is Posts table and seconds is Comments table.
I'm using sqlite database.

I'm getting null as result for comment function using hasMany method in Post Model.

Posts table migration file:

```
    class CreatePostsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('Posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('name');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::drop('Posts');
    }
}
```

Comments table migration file:

```
 class CreateCommentsTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
{
    Schema::create('Comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('post_id')->unsigned()->index();
        $table->text('body');
        $table->timestamps();
    });
        Schema::table('Comments', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->foreign('post_id')->refrences('id')->on('Posts');
        });
}


/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::drop('Comments');
}
}
```

Post Model:

```
class Post extends Model
{

    //
    public function comment(){
    return $this->hasMany(Comment::class);    
   //I have also tried: return $this->hasMany(Comment::class,'post_id','id');
    }
}
```

The data has been entered in both the tables and I'm getting results when I do

```
$post=new App\Post;
$post->get();
```

But when I try to get all the comments for a post using

```
$post->comment;
```

I'm getting

```
=>Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection {#633
all:[],
}
```

Why am I getting null as a result?

Answer (score 0):

You're not. You're getting an empty Collection object. This means there are no results for your post found.

You can do `$post->comment->count() === 0` and get true.

Your relationship appears wrong. You said you tried something else; that one looks more correct,  going by the documentation.
https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent

`return $this->hasMany('App\Comment', 'foreign_key', 'local_key');`

With this, if you are still getting an empty set as a return, I would encourage you to install the Laravel debug bar and check out the raw SQL being ran. Your data is either incorrect or there is some problem that isn't being explained in your post.

Edit: You can also try setting up a `belongsTo` relationship on the Comment for good measure.